# Magento - Determine what pages is available to handle

Tags: php, magento

how can i determine what pages is available to handle in magento layout files? after default handle (which shows up on almost every page) there're few handles for example :

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
........
</checkout_cart_index>
```

which goes to the checkout cart page.

while the file in app/design/frontend/mypackage/mytheme/template/ contains .phtml for function in each block, how can i know where is the list of php page for the website?

Comment: You should understand first how magento's "frontend" works: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-4.html

Comment: @Shaz i even finished reading the designer guide for magento 1.x for developers in PDF

Comment: Then you know that Magento doesn't have php pages when it comes to templates. It builds a layout according to the current controller action and the include the respective templates (.phtml).

Comment: yea i thought about that , but regarding this 

If Magento finds handles other than <default>, it will assign the updates nested inside the handle to the according page specified by the handle. For instance, <catalog_product_view> contains the layout updates for the Product View page, while <catalog_product_compare_index> contains those for the Compare Product page. 

which is taken from the pdf, i thought that handler also means pages right? @Shaz

Comment: No, layout handles are not pages, you can even create custom ones, there is another explanation: http://blog.belvg.com/layout-xml-directives-handles-block-reference-action-remove-update.html